# React.js search bar always fetches the same content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm building a search engine with React.js, where I can look for GIPHY gifs using their API. Everytime I type a word(any word), it always loads the same gifs and when I erase and write another word, the gifs don't update.

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react'; //react library
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //react DOM - to manipulate elements
import './index.css';
import SearchBar from './components/Search';
import GifList from './components/SelectedList';

class Root extends React.Component { //Component that will serve as the parent for the rest of the application.

constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        gifs: []
    }
    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this)
}

handleTermChange(term) {
    console.log(term);
    let url = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${term.replace(/\s/g, '+')}&api_key=aOfWv08Of7UqS6nBOzsO36NDvwYzO6io';
        fetch(url).
    then(response => response.json()).then((gifs) => {
        console.log(gifs);
        this.setState({
            gifs: gifs
        });
    });
};  


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onTermChange={this.handleTermChange} />
        <GifList gifs={this.state.gifs} />
      </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( <Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**search.js**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

import './Search.css'

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
onInputChange(term) {
    this.props.onTermChange(term);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="search">
            <input placeholder="Enter text to search for gifs!" onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**Giflist:**

```
import React from 'react';
import GifItem from './SelectedListItem';

const GifList = (props) => {
console.log(props.gifs);
  const gifItems = props.gifs && props.gifs.data && props.gifs.data.map((image) => { 
    return <GifItem key={image.id} gif={image} />
});

  return (
 <div className="gif-list">{gifItems}</div>
  );
};

export default GifList;
```

**GifItem:**

```
import React from 'react';

const GifItem = (image) => {
  return (
<div className="gif-item">
  <img src={image.gif.images.downsized.url} />
</div>
  )
};

export default GifItem;
```

I can't seem to find where is the issue here. Is it because of `this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this)` and there is no "update" state after?

Any help is welcome :) Thanks!

Comment: can you show `GifList` component?

Comment: I have updated the question. @Mayank Shukla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because, you are not putting the term value entered by user in the url, all the time you hit the api with static value `term`, here:

```
'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${term.replace(/\s/g, '+')}&api_key=aOfWv08Of7UqS6nBOzsO36NDvwYzO6io';
```

Replace `'` by ' (tick), like this:

```
let url = `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${term.replace(/\s/g, '+')}&api_key=aOfWv08Of7UqS6nBOzsO36NDvwYzO6io`;
```

Check MDN Doc for more details about **[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**.

Comment: Aahh! Before I thought the problem was related with the API url. Thanks!  @Mayank Shukla